# Best way to override SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have worked on a project for 1 month and there are 6 entities without any relationship with other entities. They are all simple entities.

We have created 6 different classes for operations on each entity. `SaveOrUpdateEntity()` methods of classes are almost same as you think. It is something like that:

```
public static ErrorType SaveOrUpdateEntity(Entity entity, int userID)
{
    try
    {
        using (DataEntities ctx = new DataEntities())
        {
            if (entity != null)
            {
                if (entity.entityID == 0)
                {
                    entity.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                    entity.CreatedBy = userID;

                    ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                {
                    entity.ModifyDate = DateTime.Now;
                    entity.ModifiedBy = userID;

                    ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        return ErrorType.NoError;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ErrorType.SaveError;
    }
}
```

It would be very helpful, if `SaveOrUpdateEntity()` method is shorter and more generic by overriding `SaveChanges()` method. According to other questions, articles, and posts about overriding `SaveChanges()` method, implementing interface that stores state of entities is a good solution but I am also wondering other solutions.

Because I am newbie, all answers would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can do the following

1- create an Interface in your application that all the classes that has the following properties will implement this interface: Id, CreatedDate,CreatedBy, ModifiedDate,ModifiedBy

```
public interface ITrack
{
      int Id{get; set;}
      int CreatedBy{get; set;}
      DateTime CreatedDate{get; set;}
      int? ModifiedBy{get; set;} // int? because at first add, there is no modification
      DateTime? ModifiedBy {get; set;}
}
```

> **Best practices** Define the `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy` as `string` which will be good for performance and maintenance

2- Add a class `TrackableEntry` which implements the interface `ITrack`

```
public abstract class TrackableEntry : ITrack
{
      public int Id{get; set;}
      public int CreatedBy{get; set;}
      public DateTime CreatedDate{get; set;}
      public int? ModifiedBy{get; set;} 
      public DateTime? ModifiedBy {get; set;}
}
```

3- remove the properties mentioned in the interface from all of your classes and let these classes to implement directly from `TrackableEntry`

```
public class A: TrackableEntry
{
    //public int Id{get; set;}
    //public int CreatedBy{get; set;}
    //public DateTime CreatedDate{get; set;}
    //public int? ModifiedBy{get; set;}
    //public DateTime? ModifiedBy {get; set;}
}
```

4- In your `DbContext` file override your `SaveChanges` and add property `UserId`  or `UserName` if you followed the `*Best practices*` part

```
public int UserId{get; set;}

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var added = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Added)
                .Select(t => t.Entity)
                .ToArray();

    foreach (var entity in added)
    {
        if (entity is ITrack)
        {
            var track = entity as ITrack;
            track.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            track.CreatedBy = UserId;
        }
    }

    var modified = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Modified)
                .Select(t => t.Entity)
                .ToArray();

    foreach (var entity in modified)
    {
        if (entity is ITrack)
        {
            var track = entity as ITrack;
            track.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            track.ModifiedBy = UserId;
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

finally in your forms when you want to call `SaveChanges` method, ensure you set the `UserId` or `UserName` value

```
var entities=new Entities(); // assuming that your DbContext file called Entities
// code for adding or deletion or modification here
entities.As.Add(new A(){...});

// ....

entities.UserId=MyUser;
entities.SaveChanges();
```

hope this will help you

Comment: `ITrack` is only an interface, you'll need to implement those properties in a concrete class - step 2 should be skipped.

Comment: Actually, I missed a part to implement a base class `TrackableEntry` which will implement the `ITrack` and all classes should inherits from this `TrackableEntry`, i will include this update

Answer (score 3):

This code will be better with :

```
    var added = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(t => t.Entity is ITrack && t.State == EntityState.Added)
            .Select(t => t.Entity)
            .ToArray();
```

The same for modified :

```
    var modified = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(t => t.Entity is ITrack && t.State == EntityState.Modified)
            .Select(t => t.Entity)
            .ToArray();
```

And remove if conditions in foreach loop...

Answer (score 1):

To 'override' `SaveChanges` without needing to create all that extra code, I wrapped it in its own extension method. i.e.

```
public static int SaveChangesWrapped(this MyDbContext db)
{
    // do other things

    return db.SaveChanges();
}
```

or async...

```
public static Task<int> SaveChangesAsyncWrapped(this MyDbContext db)
{
    // do other things

    return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

You can tweak it however you need, i.e. add other parameters, make it generic, etc. I may be missing something but this was enough for me to 'override' `SaveChanges` and cut down a whole lot of repeated code.

Then anywhere in your code when you want to save, it's just:

```
db.SaveChangesWrapped();

//or

await db.SaveChangedAsyncWrapped();
```