# Is there something like OnDelete callback for ASP.NET Core model?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following model:

```
 public class MyFiles
    {
        public int MyFilesId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can understand it's a model for uploaded files. Each model keeps path to `wwwroot/ ...` and  file's (image for example) name. But how to delete a file when I delete this model? I mean:

```
var res = _applicationDbContext.MyFiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyFilesId = 666);
_applicationDbContext.MyFiles.Remove(res);
_applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Of course, the above code will not delete file. It would very useful if I can write something like:

```
 public class MyFiles
    {
        public int MyFilesId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }

        protected OnDelete() { // here is logic for removing the file from OS }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no event mechanism to subscribe to in EF. What you could do though would be to override the `SaveChanges` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908301/best-way-to-override-savechanges/26908556)

What is described is a variation of the following:

```
public interface IFileSystemEntity
{
      string Path { get; set; }
}

public class MyFiles: IFileSystemEntity
{
    public int MyFilesId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }

    protected OnDelete() { // here is logic for removing the file from OS }
}
```

And then in your DBContext

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var added = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                .Select(t => t.Entity)
                .ToArray();

    foreach (var entity in added)
    {
        if (entity is IFileSystemEntity)
        {
            var track = entity as IFileSystemEntity;
            // Remove logic here
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct callback but you can override `OnSave()` in your DbContext and call the delete method there there.

```
public class MyFiles
{
  public int MyFilesId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Path { get; set; }

  protected OnDelete() { // here is logic for removing the file from OS }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
  public override int SaveChanges()
  {
    // iterate through deletions
    foreach (var item in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted))
    {
      // if item being deleted is MyFiles, call OnDelete
      if (item.Entity is MyFiles myFile)
        myFile.OnDelete();
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

I'm unaware of how long it will take to delete the file from the OS, how often this will happen and how important it is to delete the file immediately. However, if it takes time to delete a file adding this logic could considerably slow down your `context.SaveChanges()` calls. To avoid this I would consider adding 'files to be deleted' to some sort of queue so that these can be processed independantly of the save operation on the dbcontext.

Comment: Thank you! it's so strange that there is no default mechanize for this task. I'm new in .NET world. I have come from PHP (from Laravel framework). In Laravel there are events for Before delete and After delete. It upsets me ((

Answer (score 1):

You can override method SaveChanges() and call in it to check deleted object in ChangeTracker and call your callback

```
public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    {
        foreach (var entityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Deleted))
        {
            var oldEntity = entityEntry.Entity;
            // my callback
        }

        return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    }
```