# Getting all errors on an SaveChanges() within EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

All,
I need to show all validation errors within EF Core. So for example

I get data by doing this :

```
    foreach (var item in FRFT)
        {
            var FinancialReportingFrameworkType = new FinancialReportingFrameworkType { FinancialReportingFrameworkTypeId = item.Frfid, Acronym = item.Frf1, Name = item.Frfdescription };
            _clDBContext.FinancialReportingFrameworkType.Add(FinancialReportingFrameworkType);
        }
```

Then I want to push this data into another table but there may be some vlaidation errors. I need to track the errors.

If I do a try .. catch block, I only recieve the first error but there maybe an error on every single row I push into the databse.

> ```
>   _clDBContext.SaveChanges();
>             
>         }
>         catch (DbUpdateException e)
>         {
>             if (e.InnerException != null)
>             {
>                 // to be chnged to an POST HTML error code 
>                 Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
>                 return new OkObjectResult(e.InnerException.Message);
>             }
> ```

I need to do some pre-Save Changes valdiation.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Override `SaveChanges` in your DbContext. And validate before Save.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - is this the only way ? Do you have an example ?

Comment: If you want to validate modified object, it is best way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908301/best-way-to-override-savechanges

Comment: I did an quick try..catch like above but can only get the first error ? Is there a way i can proceed with that instead ? Why is it only giving me the first error when the savechanges has got all these rows that need updating ?

Comment: It gives you one error because it's an error from a database, and database SQL has no such feature as data validation. Instead, it always returns the first error that prevents SQL from executing. If you need to validate you data, then it's better to validate it on the level above EF, where the input data is being prepared. Search for `Validating using DataAnnotation` for example